# Replace pip install to poetry in arflow

Tags: python, dockerfile, airflow, python-poetry

I have a Dockerfile with Airflow

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.7.1-python3.11
... several COPY ...
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r /requirements.txt
```

And it works like a charm, but I want to use poetry instead of it. And that's the file I've got.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.7.1-python3.11
... several COPY ...
RUN pip install poetry
COPY ./pyproject.toml /opt/airflow/pyproject.toml
WORKDIR /opt/airflow/
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
```

But while build I've got information:
`Creating virtualenv dwh-sxWGcd-a-py3.11 in /home/airflow/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs`

If I do `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` poetry install trying to install everything into the `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` instead of `/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` and I've got permission error (seems that it uses system directory)

And my question is: Is it possible to do installation to local folder (like already existing `/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`) with poetry without any virtual env?

Comment: Airflow docs explain why poetry is not supported due constraint vs. requirements management https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#installation-tools